# How to set the width of a layout in Android?

Tags: java, android

Is there     Any  way    to    set  the  width  of the  Layout.

Because   most   of the   time  it  doesn't    work?

Comment: What doesn't work? What have you tried?

Comment: Very open ended question. What is with SO today, 5 upvotes for such a terrible question ?

Answer (score 18):

If you're doing it the XML way you'd use the layout_width attribute:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width ="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

If you're doing it programatically you'd use the LayoutParams:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
parentView.addView(ll, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: thanks.Can     we    fixed   a  child    in a  particular  Layout.
I   have    a    relative  Layout .Under   that   I have   taken  one    linear Layout   and   and   a   button    horizontically.I  have   also    set   the   width   of the   linear Layout.but   the   button    appear     at   the  first   place.I want  this   button    at the   end.

Comment: In that case you'd use one of the alternate addView() methods... for example addView(View child, int index, LayoutParams params). See (ViewGroup)[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html] for a full listing.

Comment: This does not work if you have an inner layout which it's width/height is less than the width/height you request. The actual value will be the minimum of both.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `layout_width` or `width` attributes to your layout. Example:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="100dip" />
```

Comment: This won't work unless it's prefixed with "android:".

Comment: fyi: "android" is a xml-namespace which is defined earlier in the document: xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Answer (score 1):

```
<WhateverLayout ... android:layout_width='xxxdip' />
```

Comment: but     how   to   do  it  programitically    without    using   xml